# Commutation and triggering angle

Tags: bridge-rectifier, commutation

I have circuit to analyze like this:

[image]

- L = 5 mH
- Vs = 230 V (RMS)
- Iload = 10 A constant
- Vda = 100 V

I should calculate commutation (u) and the triggering angle but both are unknown. I tried to find both by calculating average DC voltage with the formula below:

$$ V_{ort} = \frac{A}{T}\left(cos(\alpha) + cos(u) - 2 \right) $$

I couldn't find them because there are two undefined variables. I found a formula that is used for a bridge rectifier which is designed with diodes and modified it, but didn't work.

Found formula:

$$\cos\mu = 1-\frac{\omega L_s}{V_{max}}I_d$$

$$ cos(\alpha) - cos(\alpha + u) = \frac{\omega L_s I_d}{V_{max}} $$

Which I modified.

I tried to combine both formulas but it didn't work.

At last, I sent a message to my teacher to get some tricks and he said calculate the commutation losses, add the commutation losses to the average DC voltage and calculate the triggering angle as if there were no commutation, but I guess there is nothing to calculate the commutation losses.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: All SCR's use PNPN junctions effectively 2 diode drops each 0.7V + I*Rd = voltage drop so a 10A SCR may be rated near 2V drop or 20W loss. But every datasheet depends on the heatsink, junction resistance, power rating and junction temperature

Comment: This is an AC-DC full bridge so phase angle matters and load reactance + ESR too for caps or DCR for DC motors

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 You can think all diodes are ideal. I should calculate commutation losses. Commutation losses is exist because of the L enductance.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 voltage phase angle is zero. Also load is puerly enductive because of constant current.

Comment: Inductor current integrates voltage and is not constant unless R current limited

Comment: As current load is constant ... This is a PD2 circuit with "heavy" internal generator inductor impedance. Should use the classic " average" formula * cos(angle firing).

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that is excatly suitable for my situation. You can check it if you have same or similar problem with me.

[Here the article](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-811407-0.00008-8)